# Can I use relative fast queries in the SitecoreQuery attribute?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I have a working installation of Sitecore 7 + Glass Mapper 3 which I am looking to optimize.

An example of my code is:

```
[SitecoreQuery(".//*[@@templateid = '{011EC776-D9F3-4D73-8D8D-E454417E7574}']", 
                                                               IsRelative = true)]
IEnumerable<ItineraryLine> Itinerary { get; set; }
```

I was hoping to use FastQuery but I get the error:

> End of string expected at position 4

I gave the [following solution a try](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/10/Support-Relative-Fast-Queries-for-Lookup-Fields-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) this involves slotting in to the `getLookupSourceItems` pipeline - but I don't think this is the right pipeline as it doesn't trigger in debug.

Is there another pipeline (if at all) that Glass uses in this scenario? Is there a different way I can solve my goal of speeding this up?

If I wasn't using attributes but extension methods I could do this manually and use `*[@@id='']` to set the root node, but I was hoping to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the IsRelative setting to true GMS pushes the query throught Axes SelectItem. Sitecore does not allow fast query for Axes selects, e.g.:

```
Item.Axes.SelectItems("fast:./*");
```

See documentation here page 3:

http://www.iosh.co.uk/~/media/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.ashx

However GMS being awesome allows us to solve this another way, you can put placeholders in your query that GMS will expand. Removing the IsRelative property and using the {path}
placeholder allows the same result:

```
[SitecoreQuery("fast:{path}//*[@@templateid = '{011EC776-D9F3-4D73-8D8D-E454417E7574}']")]
IEnumerable<ItineraryLine> Itinerary { get; set; }
```

The path placeholder will be expanded to the full path of the current item being mapped.

Comment: I'm still getting the error "End of string expected at position 32" - I can't seem to find out what {path} is being replaced with to debug this further. I also copy/pasted what you wrote just to make sure. Thanks so far!

Comment: I just copy and pasted it again and it worked fine for me. Can you paste your code into here again?

Comment: Could it be the path has items with keyword names in it, which Glass isn't handling? i.e 'and'. I know that database.SelectItems(query) will struggle with paths unless they've been escaped in the query.

Comment: I had the same problem and found that I can use {escapedPath} instead of {path}